# Is LOTRO On topic?

Tags: discussion

I know it's a game, not the books or movie, but the Lord of the Rings Online game has its own rich contribution to the LotR  world.  I haven't found any references to it here, though.

In many ways I find the story in this universe to greatly complement the original.

Thoughts? **Is LOTRO On topic?**

Comment: We've got [158 questions tagged "video-games"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games).

Comment: Possible dupe: [Can I ask a question about video game based scifi/fantasy?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/319/143)

Answer (score 11):

LOTRO is described ([by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_Online)) as a...

> ...massively multiplayer online role-playing game set in a fantasy
>   universe based upon J. R. R. Tolkien's Middle-earth writings. It takes
>   place during the time period of The Lord of the Rings.

Assuming your question is about the *universe explored within the game* then absolutely yes, these questions would be totally on topic here. It's fantasy and it's fiction which means it's right for SF&**F**:SE

---

If your questions are about the game's mechanics, the stats of various characters, walkthroughs, etc then the answer would be a decided **no**. Those questions would be better answered on another stack, perhaps [Gaming:SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

We've already got several questions for the game [*Shadow of Mordor*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-of-mordor), which like Lord of the Rings Online is not in *Tolkien's canon*, but exists in the same universe. Those questions have been well-received, and as long as you follow the specifications that Richard pointed out, go ahead and post them!

Just make sure if you ask about some part of the world that may exist in the books/movies as well, that you specify you are asking from a *game perspective*, unless you want all views.